# deployment of owin class library to iis causes 404

Tags: .net, iis-7.5, owin

I'm getting 404 once i deploy it to the under IIS sites with 4.0 intergrate pipeline. I'm trying to access some web api route like so https://appname.domainname.com/api/v1/SomeObject/GetAll.

As Console Application it worked just fine.

My Startup file

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(XXX.Owin.Startup))]
namespace XXX.Owin
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private static readonly Logger s_logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            s_logger.Info("Start");

            HttpConfigurationManager httpConfigurationManager = new HttpConfigurationManager();
            HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = httpConfigurationManager.Create();

            appBuilder.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);

            appBuilder.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
            {
                Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopwatch.Start();

                await next();

                stopwatch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Request took: {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            });


            appBuilder.Use<CustomHeadersComponent>();
            appBuilder.Use<SecurityComponent>();
            appBuilder.UseWebApi(httpConfiguration);
        }
    }
```

Should i add web.config ? 
change app.config to web.config ?
maybe i cannot create iis site and set physical path to owin directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that the project was Windows Library and not Web Application.